# JavaScript Jest Testing Using fetch() and getting 'Undefined' from JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, jestjs, fetch

I am learning fetch and javascript testing using jest. I've encountered the following problem and have tried to resolve it but failed:

I am trying to validate some data from JSON from https://reqres.in/api/users/1 using JavaScript Jest testing via fetch() to fetch the data from JSON. But it returns failed as (see also screenshot attached):

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected)    // deep equality
Expected: "George"
Received: undefined
```

[image]

The JSON data from https://reqres.in/api/users/1:

```json
data:
  id    1
  email "george.bluth@reqres.in"
  first_name    "George"
  last_name "Bluth"
  avatar "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
```

Here is what I've done:

I created a `user.js` file which has a function called `fetchData()` to fetch the data from https://reqres.in/api/users/1. The `fetchData()` code:

```
function fetchData(){
    return fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/1')
              .then(response => response.json());
});
```

I also created a `user.test.js` test file as:

```
const fetchData = require('./user');
test('Verify first name', () => {
    return fetchData().then(data => {
    expect(data.first_name).toEqual('George');
    });
});
```

when I run the test (`npx jest user.test.js`), it returned failed and showed the result as indicated above. The test should pass as the JSON data for first name matches the expected string "George". I think the problem here is that the data that was returned by JSON somehow is incorrect and so it says undefined. How should I correct my code?

I've tried a number of ways trying to fix this error, including using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to return the JSON data in order to compare with the expected string, but both not successful. I'm at this point not sure what I have done incorrectly. Can someone help me in pinpointing to me why it says undefine?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please, revert the last edit, you killed the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The response is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
    "first_name": "George",
    "last_name": "Bluth",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
  },
  "ad": {
    "company": "StatusCode Weekly",
    "url": "http://statuscode.org/",
    "text": "A weekly newsletter focusing on software development, infrastructure, the server, performance, and the stack end of things."
  }
}
```

There is `data` key in the response, so it should be:

```
test('Verify first name', () => {
    return fetchData().then(data => {
        expect(data.data.first_name).toEqual('George');
    });
});
```

Comment: That solved it!! thank you so much Estus. Now it returned pass, which should be. But can you explain to me why there's an additional data as in data.data.first_name?